# How does Base32 encoding work in Java?

Tags: java, base32

I have this code to generate a random key.

```
new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
```

From what I understand, the first part of the code will create a 130 bit, random, integer. Then, the `.toString(int radix)` method will be called on it and the number will be converted to an alpha-numeric string.

What I can't understand is which alphabet is used for the characters; in other words, which key is mapped to which character?

**Note:** I looked for how a [Base 32 conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) can happen, but I couldn't come up with anything useful since it doesn't seem to be a unique method to do that.

Comment: What research did you do before asking the question? Combining the wikipedia entry with a *tiny* bit of experimentation should make it pretty obvious. (Just creating `BigInteger` values for 0-31 and calling `toString(32)` on them would have done, too...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29) says:

> *" The digit-to-character mapping provided by [`Character.forDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit%28int,%20int%29) is used, and a minus sign is prepended if appropriate."*.

And the latter javadoc says:

> *" If the digit is less than 10, then '0' + digit is returned. Otherwise, the value 'a' + digit - 10 is returned."*

Comment: I went there and I didn't catch anything useful at a first read. Thank you for that :)

Comment: @domenicop - It always pays to read the javadocs *carefully*.  Assume that the information is there, and you missed it at first glance.  (It usually is ...)